# 1 sec pass for the person rode on light

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light

I heard that moving object is time passed slower than stopped object is.
Then, if stopped object passed 1 sec, does how much time passed 'person A' rode on light?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing to clear is that any object with mass will **never** be able to move at light speed and ride along with light as it would require infinite energy.

For just a perspective suppose for a light beam/photon, as it is traveling at light speed it experiences no time at all relative to other observers. Its time has stopped and so 1 second outside would be **zero** seconds for that object as seen from the perspective of the stationary object. Note that the object traveling at light speed ( the beam/photon) would instead think it itself is stationary with time passing normally for it while the rest of the world would be frozen in time.

Comment: If an observer is time dilated, the rest of the universe seems to run faster.